# Examples on how to use the word "prima" in German

Tags: german-to-english

Can you please tell me how German speakers use the word prima in a few examples? I looked it up on Google translate and it says it means "fine".

Comment: https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=prima

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? I assume you have already consulted dictionaries?

Comment: So, when you already found the translation (prima = fine): What else do you want to know?

Comment: @tallistroan: errm - as usual these Linguee entries have much room for improvment at best, I don't think they will help much here. In German: *Wenn Linguee hier als "General Reference" durchgeht, dann Gut' Nacht.*

Comment: *prima* is an uninflected adjective: *eine prima Sache*, *das sind prima Schuhe*. Used mostly in colloquial German.

Comment: This is a legitimate question. It is well part of "usage and rules of the German language" to see typical examples for the usage of a word in everyday communication. I do not understand the "close" votes. I would like to answer this questions, but I cannot as it is curently "closed".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: go ahead ;)

Comment: Please do not capitalise German words just because they appear in a title, in German capitalisation has a grammatical function. Indeed: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Prima_Klasse_Gymnasium

Comment: Another link to a dictionary entry with lots of examples [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/prima).

Comment: @Takkat I agree with you, that Linguee should not be a general reference. However in this case there are at least four quite good example sentences including a translation. I don't see how this doesn't help the questioner at all. In the end I did not post it as an answer on purpose because I did not put any effort in presenting the example use cases of the word prima

Comment: @tallistroan of course it does help us native speakers, because we already know what is correct. This is different with a non-native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common example that I can think of would be "Das hast du prima gemacht!" which is pretty much the equivalent of "good job". So it's a little bit stronger than just fine.